# How can I work out the time complexity of the following SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, time-complexity

There is a list of users' transactions. Each user has multiple transactions. I have written the following code to find the most recent transactions of the users and then pick the users who haven't had any transactions in the last seven days or more but I don't know what the time complexity of my code is. Can someone explain how I can workout the time complexity of my code?

the trans_date is the transaction date.

```
select user_id,_date,datediff(curdate(),_date) 
 from(
      select t1.send_id as user_id,from_unixtime(t1.trans_date) as _date
      from transactionhistory as t1
      where from_unixtime(t1.trans_date) = 
                    (select max(from_unixtime(t2.trans_date))    
                     from transactionhistory as t2
                     where t2.send_id = t1.send_id)) as tab         
where datediff(curdate(),_date) > 7;
```

Here is the output of the EXPLAIN command

[image: see image here]

Comment: The first step would be to get your system to explain it's execution plan for the query.  In what environment are you running ? If it is Hadoop use the EXPLAIN <my-query> command and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Richard  I have added the output of the EXPLAIN <my-query> command to my question. It's Sql server environment. Can you help me workout the time complexity now?

Answer (score 0):

Is the query correct ?

In order to process per user then innermost query be `from ... t2 where t2.send_id = t1.send_id`.  If it is not you are only selecting the newest record of the one user with the newest transaction overall.

I think it would be O ( n^2 ). An outer O(n) loop and an inner O(n) loop.

Comment: You are right! I had accidentally removed that line while editing the question details. I have added it back now.